# What was the highest mountain climbed without supplemental oxygen, and the lowest one climbed with oxygen, before Messner's 1970 Nanga Parba ascent?

Tags: mountaineering, high-altitude, history

I wonder what the highest mountain (or highest elevation above sea level, not necessarily a summit) had been that was climbed without oxygen and the lowest one that was climbed with oxygen out of fear of lethal altitude sickness prior to Reinhold Messner's ascent of Nanga Parbat in 1970. How did the climbing altitude record without supplemental oxygen change over time?

Comment: Does the "before Messner..." part apply to both the "highest without" and the "lowest with" questions, or only to the "lowest with" question?

Comment: @JoryGeerts It applies to both. Why would you think otherwise? Messner was the first (along with companions) who ascended all 26,000ers (8,000ers) without supplemental oxygen, wasn't he?